# laravel 5.4 form dropdown from database

Tags: php, database, forms, laravel, dropdown

I want to fetch drop down option value & name from database, to do that my controller code is

```
 $roles = Role::pluck('role','user_id');
 return view('users.add_role',compact('roles'));
```

to fetch this data from drop down list my view file code is

```
<select name="role" class="form-control" >
          @foreach($roles as $role)
            <option value="{{ $role->user_id }} "> {{ $role->role }} </option>
          @endforeach
</select>
```

but it says error

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\auth2\resources\views\users\add_role.blade.php)
```

if i just only use

```
<select name="role" class="form-control" >
      @foreach($roles as $role)
        <option value="{{ $role }} "> {{ $role }} </option>
      @endforeach
</select>
```

then it shows role column of the table, but it not pass option value to database. so what is the correct way to generate option value & name from database?

Comment: dd($roles) and show the output

Comment: just checked, it only pass role column data, not user_id column

Comment: Pluck returns only 1 column. If you pass in 2 variables, it will change the name of the array key. (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck)

Comment: @Masum share your role table structure. I doubt you have a user_id column on your role table. Since user roles are mostly stored in a pivot table.

Comment: yes u r right, in this project i did not use pivot table, user_id field is under roles table

Comment: @sanseesh i think to assign a role to user its easy user_id field into roles table, may be am wrong,  i just trying to learn all possible way

Answer (score 0):

Your `$roles` variable containt an array which is looks like

```
[0] => 'your_role'
[1] => 'your_role'
```

Where is 0 and 1 index is user_id. So your `user_id` is set as an index of your `$roles` array. Simply do it `dd($roles)` and check the output.  $key as $role will work. Where $key will containt the `user_id`.

```
 @foreach($roles as $key => $role)
      <option value="{{ $key }} "> {{ $role }} </option>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: not works, it only pass role column, just checked by          return dd($roles);

Comment: Collection {#90 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    1 => "Admin"
    0 => "Manager"
  ]
}

Comment: it's not clear. please show an image or update your question by this debug result in a good format.

Answer (score 0):

I use laravel collective package to generate dropdown list much more easier,
you can do things like, on your blade template and it will render the list for you

{{ Form::select('role', $role )) }}